# Getting substring based on particular index in xsl/xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a long web url in my xsl variable. 
eg.
@url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/2434/35454"

I need a substring from this based on 3rd index of "/". i.e I want to display only
http://stackoverflow.com

There is a substring(string, start, length) function in xsl but how do i find the length portion. I could not find any indexof function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(url,1,length)"/>
```

My url is suppose - "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/2434/35454"
Output I want is http://stackoverflow.com

Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
   concat(substring-before(.,'//'),
          '//',
          substring-before(substring-after(., '//'),
                           '/'
                           )
         )
```

**Complete code example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(substring-before(.,'//'),
          '//',
          substring-before(substring-after(., '//'),
                           '/'
                           )
         )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/2434/35454</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: So if my url is stored in $url I have to use like  this.                concat(substring-before(url,'//'),           '//',           substring-before(substring-after(url, '//'),                            '/'                            )

Comment: @AbhiRoczz... Yes, but don't forget the `$` character before the name of the variable.